# how to use /dev/ptmx for create a virtual serial port?

Tags: python, linux, serial-port

I have a program, using pyserial, and I want to test it without using a real serial port device.

In windows, I use com0com, and in linux, I know there is a method to create virtual serial port pair without using additional program.

so I look up the manual, and found pts, /dev/ptmx, but I don't know how to create a pair by following the manual, can anyone give me a example?

I tried(in python):

```
f = open("/dev/ptmx", "r")
```

and it works, /dev/pts/4 is created.

and I tried:

```
f = open("/dev/4", "w")
```

and the result is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IOError: [Errno 5] Input/output error: '/dev/pts/4'
```

edit:
I found a solution(workround), using socat.

```
socat PTY,link=COM8 PTY,link=COM9
```

then COM8 COM9 are created as virtual serial port pair.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per [the docs](http://linux.die.net/man/4/ptmx), you need [ptsname](http://linux.die.net/man/3/ptsname) to get the name of the slave-side of the pseudo-terminal, and also, quoting the docs,

> Before opening the pseudo-terminal
>   slave, you must pass the master's file
>   descriptor to grantpt(3) and
>   unlockpt(3).

You should be able to use `ctypes` to call all of the needed functions.

Comment: are there any example? C/python/C++?

Comment: I found a long C example, http://www.developerweb.net/forum/showthread.php?t=5623 , but no Python examples.

Comment: Python examples are hidden in the `pty` module, although it conveniently lets `os.openpty` do the actual work when it can :)

Comment: openpty is great, and I can use it for IPC, but not fit for testing another program using serial port...

Comment: If openpty isn't fit, then I don't see how you expect to use the (exact same) terminal you get from managing /dev/ptmx yourself.

Answer (score 6):

I was trying to make an application that made use of virtual serial ports in order to communicate with some remote devices using TCP/Serial conversion... and I came across to a problem similar to yours. My solution worked out as follows:

```
import os, pty, serial

master, slave = pty.openpty()
s_name = os.ttyname(slave)

ser = serial.Serial(s_name)

# To Write to the device
ser.write('Your text')

# To read from the device
os.read(master,1000)
```

Although the name of the port of the master is the same if you check (/dev/ptmx) the fd is different if you create another master, slave pair, so reading from the master gets you the message issued to his assigned slave. I hope this helps you or anyone else that comes across a problem similar to this one.

Comment: you should consider using one pyserial's replacement: [pytty](http://hg.pytty.org/pytty/file/9ecd879bcd15/src/__init__.py#l41) which offer a way to handle the master part as well as the slave part.

Comment: Thanks. This was just what I needed to mock a serial interface for testing.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know python but I can point you in the right direction: look [here](http://www.developerweb.net/forum/showthread.php?t=5623) at a C code sample. Here's the [man](http://linux.die.net/man/4/ptmx) page for the /dev/ptmx. Make sure the permissions and owner is correct!. Here is the poster on the linuxquestions [forum](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-general-1/using-linux-pseudo-terminal-pairs-659374/) on how to use it from C.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using the `pty` module instead, which should take care of this for you. (it opens /dev/ptmx or calls `openpty` or opens another appropriate device, depending on the platform.)

Answer (score 0):

You could build a dummy object that implements the same interface as the `pySerial` classes you use, but do something completely different and easily replicable like reading from and writing to files/terminal/etc.

For example:

```
class DummySerial():
  #you should consider subclassing this
  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.fIn = open("input.raw", 'r')
    self.fOut = open("output.raw", 'w')
    pass
  def read(self, bytes = 1):
    return self.fIn.read(bytes)
  def write(self, data):
    self.fOut.write(data)
  def close(self):
    self.fIn.close()
    self.fOut.close()
  #implement more methods here
```

If it quacks like a duck and it ducks like a duck...

Comment: yet another solution...
enlightening.